# Drupal local configuration clone. Only home page is accessible

Tags: uri, users

I have cloned an existing drupal installation, the problem is, I can see only the home page, other url's are not working.My apache rewrite module is configured. I can not log in as any kind of user.

Comment: can you login as admin?

Comment: no,anything than home I cant acess

Comment: what is the error? how did you install it? using drush? the install wizard?

Comment: What does your apache log say? Is example.com/?q=user working? Where did you clone it? Local? What Drupal Version? Give us more information, so we can help you.

Comment: Apache error log say "File does not exist",installed it using wizard,in the access log returning 304

Comment: What is in your .htaccess file ? Are there any differences in what are owner, group and permission settings for both your sites and .htaccess files inside ?

Answer (score 1):

I did face with a similar problem when moving my site from local machine to dev server. but here is what i did

1. Install [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) to download the existing database and [Backup and Migrate Files](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate_files) to your local drupal installation.
2. Go to http://local-site/admin/config/system/backup_migrate and then backup the default database and local files to download
   [image: Local Database export to downloads]

[image: Public Files directory export to download]

3. Install fresh copy of drupal with new database at the server(or to the location where you are cloning.
4. Copy from http://local-site/sites/all/modules and http://local-site/sites/all/themes to their respective directories at the server(or your cloning destination)
5. Enable both the modules in step 1, from http://local-site/admin/modules
6. Go to http://cloned-site/admin/config/system/backup_migrate/restore and restore the database and local files by browsing for the exported data at step 2
   [image: Restore of the exported data]

*and don't forget to enable the theme which you used on the local-site before using backup and migrate.*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missed to update the `$base_url` from sites/default/settings.php to your new sites url. For multi-site installation please enter the appropriate url(e.g. http://clone-location/site1)